# Common file type between PHP and NODEjs to save (secret) variable data?

Tags: php, node.js, file

What exactly would be the best method to centralize information regarding sensitive information across php and nodejs? For example, port numbers and third-party tokens and secrets that I could include in .php and .js files?

Comment: The most interoperable format would be JSON; its easily created and consumed in both languages. How you store this information securely is a different matter, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using JSON is a safe choice, it can be read out of the box by both php and Nodejs.

For php you can use:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("/path/to/your/file.json"));
```

while in node you can read it with

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/file.json', 'utf8'));
```

or simply

```
var data = require('/path/to/your/file.json');
```